# how to import csv file into solr with dataimporthandler

Tags: solr

I have a solr project. I want to put my csv file data into solr using dataimporthandler. I wrote this db-data-config.xml.

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource type="FileDataSource"/>
 <document>
 <entity name="item" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" fileName="TableArchive.csv" baseDir="${solr.install.dir}/server/solr/archiveCore" dataSource="null" recursive="true" rootEntity="false">
 <field column="NameAdded" name="NameAdded" />
 <field column="DateAdded" name="DateAdded" />
 <field column="NameModified" name="NameModified" />
 <field column="DateModified" name="DateModified" />
 <field column="strSO" name="strSO" />
 <field column="strCust" name="strCust" />
 <field column="strOperator" name="strOperator" />
 <field column="PackName" name="PackName" />
 <field column="DocName" name="DocName" />
 </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I run data import handler from solr admin panel, it not indexing files. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: What is the reason for using the DIH and not the `update/csv` endpoint? I'm not sure if the DIH supports CSV files - and the `FileListEntityProcessor` is made for looping over a list of files - and then using a different processor to parse it (such as the XPath processor for XML).

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't want to use command prompt for data uploading. Because of that I decided to use DIH. If there are any solution, I can use XML,Json or something else.

Comment: In that case you're probably better off with XML. Use the FileDataSource (not FileList..) and the XPathProcessor to get the content you need from the file.